# a light Database for html 5 storage and gdrive

Tags: javascript, database, browser, angular

Hi my problem is this,

I'm developing an angular 2 app, and I have some data to save.
I prefer to save all data in json format.
the scenario is the following:

I have something like todo list, well you can add or delete some todos, but I like to save into browser store, only if customer want, he can store all data to his gdrive.

So I can't figure out how to achieve this, in pratice I'd like to use browser database like cache and save all to gdrive

You know some good javascript client library

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to see [angular-2-local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-2-local-storage) for storing data in the browser's Application Storage.

From the NPM registry:

> In your app:
>
> First you need to configure the service:

```
import { LocalStorageService, LOCAL_STORAGE_SERVICE_CONFIG } from 'angular-2-local-storage';

// Create config options (see ILocalStorageServiceConfigOptions) for deets:
let localStorageServiceConfig = {
    prefix: 'my-app',
    storageType: 'sessionStorage'
};
// Provide the config to the service:
const LOCAL_STORAGE_CONFIG_PROVIDER: Provider = provide(LOCAL_STORAGE_SERVICE_CONFIG, {
    useValue: localStorageServiceConfig
});

// Use the provider:
bootstrap(AppComponent, [LocalStorageService, LOCAL_STORAGE_CONFIG_PROVIDER]);
```

> Then you can use it in a component:

```
import { LocalStorageService } from 'angular-2-local-storage';

@Component({
    // ...
})
export class SomeComponent {
    constructor (
        private localStorageService: LocalStorageService
    ) {
        // YAY!
    }
}
```

As for Google Drive support, Google has a [pure JS API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js) but they don't seem to have an AngularJS API, let alone an Angular2 one

Cheers!